# How to fix "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable" when I use another module class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to check the type of context whether it is an instance of Context, which is in another file, but node js throws `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable.`

**index.js**

```
const Transaction = require('./Transaction');

class Context {
    constructor(uid) {
        if (typeof uid !== 'string')
            throw new TypeError('uid must be a string.');

        this.uid = uid;
    }

    runTransaction(operator) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (typeof operator !== 'function')
                throw new TypeError('operator must be a function containing transaction.');

            operator(new Transaction(this))
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Context;
```

**Transaction.js**

```
const Context = require('./index');

class Transaction {
    constructor(context) {
        // check type
        if (!(context instanceof Context))
            throw new TypeError('context should be type of Context.');

        this.context = context;
        this.operationList = [];
    }

    addOperation(operation) {

    }
}

module.exports = Transaction;
```

**Another js file**

```
let context = new Context('some uid');
context.runTransaction((transaction) => {
});
```

And there, it throws `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that you have a **circular dependency**. The other file requires `index`, `index` requires `Transaction`, and `Transaction` requires `index`. So, when `transaction` runs, it tries to require `index`, *whose module is already in the process of being built*. `index` hasn't exported anything yet, so requiring it at that time results in an empty object.

Because both must call each other, one way to solve it would be to put both classes together, and export them both:

```
// index.js
class Context {
  constructor(uid) {
    if (typeof uid !== "string") throw new TypeError("uid must be a string.");

    this.uid = uid;
  }

  runTransaction(operator) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof operator !== "function")
        throw new TypeError(
          "operator must be a function containing transaction."
        );

      operator(new Transaction(this));
    });
  }
}

class Transaction {
  constructor(context) {
    // check type
    if (!(context instanceof Context))
      throw new TypeError("context should be type of Context.");

    this.context = context;
    this.operationList = [];
    console.log("successfully constructed transaction");
  }

  addOperation(operation) {}
}

module.exports = { Context, Transaction };
```

and

```
const { Context, Transaction } = require("./index");
const context = new Context("some uid");
context.runTransaction(transaction => {});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-jones-xi1q4

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last line. But it doeasn;t fix the problem. Still show the same error.

Comment: Can you post where you're creating a Context and its associated Transaction?

Comment: See edit, you have a circular dependency, resulting in an import not being defined in time

Comment: Saved me a lot of hours! Thanks a lot!