# One empty class required, in a same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop

I have a strange problem with a require.
I have a working tree like the following:

```
./chat/
  |__ Chat.js
  |__ User.js
  |__ Message.js
./index.js
```

Each file in chat directory are classes like:

```
// some requires

class Chat {
  constructor {...}
  // some methods
}

module.exports = Chat;
```

Requires work fine... except to Chat.
For exemple, I have something like this:

```
const Chat = require("./Chat");
const Message = require("./Message");

class User {
  constructor() {
    console.log(Message); // print: [Function: Message]
    console.log(Chat); // print: {}
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

It works for Message but not for Chat. And, more strange, in another file, not in this directory, it works!

Anybody got any ideas?

EDIT: 
Here Message.js

```
"use strict";

const User = require("./User");
const InvalidTypeError = require("../error/InvalidTypeError");

class Message {
  /**
   * @param {User} sender
   * @param {string} message
   * @param {string} ip
   */
  constructor(sender, message, ip) {
    if (!(sender instanceof User)) {
      throw new InvalidTypeError("Must pass a User object");
    }

    this.timestamp = Date.now();
    this.sender = sender;
    this.message = message;
    this.ip = ip;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {number}
   */
  getTimestamp() {
    return this.timestamp;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {User}
   */
  getSender() {
    return this.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {string}
   */
  getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {string}
   */
  getIp() {
    return this.ip;
  }
}

module.exports = Message;
```

RESOLVED:
This issue caused by [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697115/how-to-fix-typeerror-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-callable-when-i-u)

Comment: Please attach the code for `Message.js`

Comment: I edited my post to add Message.js with more details. Chat class and User class made the same way.